# Numerical integration: Make template function take either only the function name or the function called with two arguments

Tags: c++, templates, numerical-integration

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to write/edit a code that integrates numerically a function using the trapezoidal rule. This works fine as long as I only pass the name of the function. However, if I pass the function with two parameters this obviously has to fail since "x" (see code) is not defined.
How can I change the code to make it work? Do I have to change something in the class "trapezium" or only in the function "integrate"?

```
#include <iostream>

// Integration routine
template<typename Method, typename F, typename Float>
double integrate(F f, Float a, Float b, long steps, Method m)
{
    double s = 0;
    double h = (b-a)/steps;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i)
    s += m (f, a + h*i, h);
    return h*s;
}

// The method
class trapezium
{
public:
    template<typename F, typename Float>
    double operator()(F f, Float x, Float h) const
    {
        return (f(x) + f(x+h))/2;
    }
};

// Test function
namespace
{
    double ftest1(double x)
    {
        return (x < 1. ? 0. : 1.);
    }

    double ftest2(double x, double amplitude)
    {
        return x < 1. ? 0. : amplitude;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //This works:
    double res1 = integrate(ftest1, 0., 2., 100, trapezium());
    std::cout << "Result 1: " << res1 << std::endl;

    //This cannot work: 
    double amplitude = 5.;
    double res2 = integrate(ftest2(x, amplitude), 0., 2., 100, trapezium());
    std::cout << "Result 2: " << res2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Unfortunately, for reasons I cannot influence I have to stick to the C++98 standard.

Comment: `std::bind` or lambda may help

Comment: you are not passing "the name of the function", but you pass a function pointer. A function pointer does not know anything about parameters, thus `integrate(myfunc,...` works, while `integrate(myfunc(x,gAmp),` is ... well .. nonsense. If you type the name of a function only, it is a function pointer. However, once you write the parameters also, the function will be evaluated to a double and you dont want to integrate a double, but a function.

Answer (score 0):

`integrate` expects a function as first argument, use a lambda or `std::bind`:

```
double res2 = integrate([=](double x) { return ftest2(x, amplitude); }, 0., 2., 100, trapezium());
// Result 2: 5.05
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work with a "functor". So instead of defining a function to pass, define a class that overrides the `operator()`:

```
class func2{
private:
    double amp;
public:
    func2(double amp) : amp(amp) {}

    double operator()(double x){return amp * stepfunction(x);}
};
```

now you can pass an instance of `func2`:

```
func2 myfunc2(5.0);
double res2 = integrate(myfunc2, 0.0, 2.0, 100.0, trapezium);
```

Comment: The functor can be build with `std::bind` or by using lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! I'm still not used to all `C++11`isms like `lambda`s :-) Both `bind` and `lambda` make the functors easier to write (like YSC's answer).